# Camel return message from direct route for reuse

Tags: apache-camel

I am very confused about returning a "body" from sub-routes called by `to()` in Camel. From what I found about direct routes is that they encourage route reuse and are used for logical splitting over-complicated routes. But I seem to fail do a simplest "split":

```
    from("jms:createRequestQueue")
            .to("direct:createRequest")

            // here the processing of the message fails, see below

            .bean(processor)

            .to("...");

    from("direct:createRequest")
            .onException(Exception.class).bean(requestErrorHandler).stop()
            .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, MyModelRequest.class);
```

The class of the processor instance looks like this:

```
public class RequestProcessor {

    @Handler
    public void update(@Body MyModelRequest request) {
        // do stuff
    }

}
```

The thing is that the result of the route for unmarshalling the request (the 2nd route) is not propagated back to the calling route. An exception is thrown saying that it cannot convert String (the JSON coming into the queue) to the MyModelRequest class. So it seems that the JSON body in the first route is not replaced by the result of the unmarshalling route. This does seem like a nice route reuse I would hope for.

I stumbled upon InOut messages, but the docs are very unclear and my experiments failed the same way.

What do I need to do to really extract parts of a route to another route for reuse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was in the onException clause (was left out of original question, I thought it wasnt the problem). I confused `end()` call with `stop()` call and so the route was stopped too soon returning the unparsed JSON in String. Correct is:

```
from("direct:createRequest")
        .onException(Exception.class).bean(requestErrorHandler).end()
        .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, MyModelRequest.class);
```

Comment: Ah, so that was it, I knew it shouldn't have been the `direct` route :)

Comment: Yeah, I also thought it should return body. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you accept this answer so that the question doesn't show up as unanswered? Thanks!

Comment: Yop. Needed to wait few hours and then I forgot. Thanks for reminder

Answer (score 0):

Without a runnable example that reporoduces theerror it's hard to tell what goes wrong but it should (and does! tested on 2.17.2 as well as 2.15.3) work:

```
@Component
public class DemoRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {   

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("timer:sender?delay=10s&period=3s")
        .setBody(constant("{\"title\":\"Lord of the Rings\",\"author\":\"J.R.R. Tolkien\"}"))
        .to("direct:unmarshal")
        .bean(new RequestProcessor())
        .log("${body}!");

    from("direct:unmarshal")
        .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Book.class);
  }

  public static class RequestProcessor {

    @Handler
    public void update(@Body Book book) {
      System.out.println("Got " + book);
    }

  }

  public static class Book {
    private final String title;

    private final String author;

    private Book() {
      this(null, null);
    }

    public Book(String title, String author) {
      this.title = title;
      this.author = author;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
      return title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
      return author;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "title='" + title + "', author='" + author + '\'';
    }

  }
}
```

Here's the output:

> 2016-08-30 13:48:34.337  INFO 16240 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication : Started DemoApplication in 5.859 seconds (JVM running for 6.587)
>
> Got title='Lord of the Rings', author='J.R.R. Tolkien'
>
> 2016-08-30 13:48:44.298  INFO 16240 --- [ timer://sender] route1 : title='Lord of the Rings', author='J.R.R. Tolkien'!
>
> Got title='Lord of the Rings', author='J.R.R. Tolkien'
>
> 2016-08-30 13:48:47.232  INFO 16240 --- [ timer://sender] route1 : title='Lord of the Rings', author='J.R.R. Tolkien'!

Comment: I probably just deleted one parameter by mistake in the json method call. Updated question. Strange that this does not work for me. It tries to cast String with the JSON to the @Body MyModelRequest class. Version is 2.15.3.

Comment: No chance of using a newer version? It may be a bug in Camel.

Comment: Tried it on 2.15.3, works perfectly fine. Can you post a runnable example of your code and also give the sample JSON?

Comment: So the problem was elsewhere, and I thought it was correct so I left it out of the question. See my answer. Thanks for your time. :)